# Limit m entities of n repetitions in SQL table

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Recently I worked with sql queries to extract required information for me. I had a table where there were a lot of repetitive values in column col1, however, for each value of this one corresponds unique value of the second column, so the table looked following:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | a1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 100 | A | a100 |
| 101 | B | b1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 234 | B | b234 |

But I needed just first 50 entities of each unique value of row1 column. Is it possible at all and if yes, how build this query in SQL. Thanks in advance! To make my thoughts more clear I provide python script of the logic:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your_table.csv')
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

unique_val = pd.unique(df.col1).tolist()

for val in unique_val:
   temp_df = df[df.col1 == val][:50]
   final_df = pd.concat([final_df, temp_df], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a row_number() function. Then selecting everything that have a rank less than 50.

```
select t.* from(
    select *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) AS rnk
    from yourtable
)t
where t.rnk < 50
```